# how to use COMMIT and ROLLBACK in a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am using three insert statements, and if there is an error in the third statement, I want to rollback the first and the second one. If there is no way to do this, please tell me a different approach to handle this in PostgresqQL.

If I use `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, I get an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST1 ()
   RETURNS VOID
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
   AS $$
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A');
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
END;$$;
```

The above code is not working; `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` are not supported by PostgreSQL functions.

Comment: This is how Postgres functions behave by default (i.e. if any of your statements fails, none will be committed).

Comment: you can achieve it with dblinks, but I would rethink the design better

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You cannot use transaction statements like `SAVEPOINT`, `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in a function.  [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) says:

> In procedures invoked by the `CALL` command as well as in anonymous code blocks (`DO` command), it is possible to end transactions using the commands `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`.

*Ex negativo*, since functions are not procedures that are invoked with `CALL`, you cannot do that in functions.

The `BEGIN` that starts a block in PL/pgSQL is different from the SQL statement `BEGIN` that starts a transaction.

Just remove the `COMMIT` from your function, and you have the solution: since the whole function is always run inside a single transaction, any error in the third statement will lead to a `ROLLBACK` that also undoes the first two statements.

Comment: posted it before testing , thanks for this information , i have done testing. it's working fine.

Comment: But in my case I need to use commit after insertion of data for pstgresql_fdw operations. So, could you suggest how to commit the data after insertion.

Comment: @UmaShankar You can use dblink for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, so if I need to update some rows in one table and by the if statement decide either should I remove the corresponding rows in another table or rollback (I mean depending on some procedural logic) then there is no way to combine if with rollback inside a function?

Comment: this is interesting, any reference from this statement > You cannot use transaction statements like SAVEPOINT, COMMIT or ROLLBACK in a function.

perhaps from the documentation ? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: @GujaratSantana I have added a quotation from the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Compared to other SQL languages, you should think that Postgres always takes care of the commit/rollback in case of error implicitly *when you are inside a transaction*.

Here is what the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) is saying:

> Transactions are a fundamental concept of all database systems. The essential point of a transaction is that it bundles multiple steps into a single, all-or-nothing operation. The intermediate states between the steps are not visible to other concurrent transactions, and if some failure occurs that prevents the transaction from completing, then none of the steps affect the database at all.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST1 ()
   RETURNS VOID
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
   AS $$
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A');
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
END;$$;
```

Comment: You cannot use transaction statements like SAVEPOINT, COMMIT or ROLLBACK in a function.

Answer (score 3):

For transaction control we use [PROCEDURE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) (From postgresql11) instead of FUCTION.
FUNCTION does not support transaction inside the function. This is the main difference between FUNCTION and PROCEDURE in PostgreSQL.

Your code should be:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1 ()
    RETURNS VOID
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$
    BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2);

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A');
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    END;$$;
```